# How do you get a tool to break a specific block in adventure mod, like on maps?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do you get a tool to break a specific block in adventure mod, like on maps?

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure if this will answer your question, but what i know is that shovels only break gravel, dirt, and sand. axes only break wood. pickaxes only break ores and rocks (stone, cobble stone, granite, etc) and swords can only hurt mobs and animals.

Comment: Ideally you should reference the Minecraft wiki and put the desired information in the body of your answer.